# HttpContext.Session.GetString("string"), Randomly I get Session has not been configured for this application or request exception

Tags: session, .net-core

Not everytime but some time i get error while i try to get HttpContext.Session.GetString("userid");
I am using .Net core 2.2

Below is my session helper code

```html
 public static class SessionHelper

    {
        private static HttpContext _context = null;

        public static void SetCurrentContext(HttpContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public static string UserID
        {
            get
            {
                try
                {
                    return _context.Session.GetString("userid");
                }
                catch
                {
                    return "";
                }
            }
            set
            {
                _context.Session.SetString("userid", value);
            }
        }
  }
```

Below in my middleware configuration in Configure method startup.cs

```html
  app.UseSession();
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "sameorigin");
                await next();
            });
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
```

Below is my ConfigureServices code of startup.cs

```html
  services.AddSession(options =>
              {
                  // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
                  options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60 * 30);
                  options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                  options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
                  //options.IOTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60 * 30);
              });
            services.AddMvc()
                .AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();
```

Comment: `SetCurrentContext` is never called... How `SessionHelper` is initialized?

Comment: In OnActionExecuting i am setting it.
SessionHelper.SetCurrentContext(filterContext.HttpContext);